# JavaScript frameworks using key-value-observing

Tags: javascript, key-value-observing

I am a CS student and I am writing a research paper on comparing Dirty Checking, key-value-observing(KVO) and Virtual DOM, and I have some questions about key-value-observing:

1. Which frameworks use key-value-observing as a change detection method nowadays?
2. Is there another term similar to "key-value-observing" I can use to search information on this method?

I would appreaciate any help on this.

Comment: you can study angular and vue js with their comparison to start with.Angular uses dirty checking whereas Vue uses event based watching of bound variables. Its a really interesting topic. Evans Yu who is one of the main founders of vue js has discussed this comparison in many if his summits which can be found on youtube. It will help you to go in depth of this research.

Comment: Thank you! Could you provide the links to Evans You summits?